# How to use cursor with LISTAGG in PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, sqlplus

I have used LISTAGG to concatenate data from two different tables to form the following output:

[image: REGION_NATION]

How do I display the above output neatly like this:

[image: desired output display]

I am using ORACLE PL/SQL. I am thinking if this can be done by implementing cursor, but I am not sure how to do it. Or maybe is there any other way to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: Please use text instead of linked images. Also it is not clear what your desired output is ( a single big string ? 5 rows with 1 column, 2 columns ? Please be more specific. The way I interpret the question you just need to concatenate the region name to the list of countries.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `NATION.N_NAME` column's datatype is `CHAR` as those names are blank-padded. I'd switch to `VARCAHR2` (if possible) or try with `TRIM`, e.g.

```
select ... 
  listagg(trim(n.n_name), ', ') within group ...
          ----
          this
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE AS 
(SELECT     r.REGION_KEY
            ,r.R_NAME
            ,LIST_AGG(trim(n.N_NAME),',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY R_NAME) AS REGION_NATION
FROM        REGION r
INNER JOIN  NATION n
        ON  r.R_REGION_KEY = n.N_REGIONKEY
GROUP BY    r.R_REGION_KEY
            ,r.R_NAME
)
SELECT      REGION_KEY
            ,R_NAME || ':' || REGION_NATION as REGION_TEXT
FROM        CTE
```